# multiple uses of attached property does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

My guess is I'm not understanding attached properties correctly.  I'm trying to convert the FlowDocument on a RichTextBox to an HTML string property in my view model.  I have two RichTextBoxes that are using my `RichTextBoxAssistant` class (thanks to [this blog post](http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor)):

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb_description" 
    local:RichTextBoxAssistant.BoundDocument="{Binding MyVM.Description,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb_descriptionHowTo"
    local:RichTextBoxAssistant.BoundDocument="{Binding MyVM.DescriptionHowTo,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

In my `RichTextBoxAssistant` class, I have this dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundDocument =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BoundDocument",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(RichTextBoxAssistant),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            boundDocumentChanged
        )
    );
```

The problem is that the `boundDocumentChanged` method gets hit when I change the value in my first RichTextBox, `rtb_description`, but not when I change the value in `rtb_descriptionHowTo`.  When I change the text or do anything to `rtb_descriptionHowTo`, I never reach `boundDocumentChanged`.  Is this a result of `RichTextBoxAssistant` being a static class?  How can I fix it so that I can use `RichTextBoxAssistant` with multiple RichTextBoxes?

Comment: Does the event on the second rich text box fire if you remove the binding on the first?

Comment: ColinE: good question.  It doesn't, so now I'm looking into other issues.  Bet it's not RichTextBoxAssistant causing the problem after all!

Comment: could it be that `DescriptionHowTo` is not a `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: Vlad: `DescriptionHowTo` is *not* a `DependencyProperty`, but its setter does call `PropertyChanged` (it's in a view model).

Answer (score 0):

[ColinE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249933/coline) had the right idea:  I tried removing the attached property from my first RichTextBox, and changing the value of the second RichTextBox still didn't put me in `boundDocumentChanged`.  Turns out my `DescriptionHowTo` property in my view model was null, instead of an HTML string.  When I initialized it to `@"<html><body></body></html>"`, things started working.